# Winsock -> WinRT Windows.Networking.Sockets -- mapping error codes

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winsock

I'm in the process of porting a C++ library to WinRT. It uses Winsock. Winsock isn't supported in WinRT. Microsoft directs you to use Windows.Networking.Sockets instead. I'm running into questions trying to map the Winsock API to the Windows.Networking.Sockets API. I've used sockets in managed code, but not in C++. I'm unfamiliar with the Winsock API.

I'm sure I will run up against other questions, but first off, I need to determine the right way to get socket error codes. I think this is the correct mapping: WSAGetLastError() == SocketError.GetStatus(hresult)

Correct?

- This doc details possible error codes using winsock: 
  [Windows Sockets Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx)
- This doc details an enumeration which I think is the equivalent, but is very different: 
  [SocketErrorStatus enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.socketerrorstatus.aspx)

The number of error codes is very different between these two. Also, WSAGetLastError() returns the error status for the last Windows Sockets operation that failed, where SocketError.GetStatus(hresult) requires an hresult as input, presumably from exception handling of a specific attempted operation. This is going to require a good bit of refactoring to make this change, so I want to make sure I've got it right before I do the work.

Lastly, is there a document someone can refer me to that defines the mapping I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinRT C++/CX socket calls that would block are all asynchronous, so they do not immediately return a result code.  When things go wrong, the async task will throw an exception, and the exception will be marshalled to the task that waits for it.  Assuming you are using [Microsoft's task library (ppltasks.h)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx), the code to connect a socket to a remote interface would look something like this:

```
StreamSocket^ socket = ref new StreamSocket();
// Assume portStr and hostName are defined elsewhere
String ^portStr;
HostName^ hostName;

task<void>(_connectSocket->ConnectAsync(hostName, portStr)).then([this] (task<void> previousTask)
{
    try
    {
        previousTask.get();
    }
    catch (Exception^ exception)
    {
        // If ConnectAsync gets an error, this is where you can catch it
        SocketErrorStatus status = SocketError.GetStatus(exception->HResult);
        // Do something interesting with HResult
    }
});
```

[Microsoft's StreamSocket example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931) has examples of making the standard socket calls has examples of how they expect the interface to be called, including error handling, except that instead of looking at the HResult, they always just print out the string version of the error message in the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I think you've answered one question: SocketError.GetStatus(hresult) is the replacement for WSAGetLastError(). Correct?

This is a good code example for using StreamSocket in a new project, but I've got an existing cross platform library that abstracts the use of Winsock or BSD sockets, depending on the target platform. It attempts to provide a common API, but I think it maps better to BSD than to this new stuff. 

Any chance you know of some documentation that maps Winsock to Windows.Networking.Sockets?

Comment: @Robert, SocketError.GetStatus is not really a direct replacement for WSAGetLastError, SocketError.GetStatus(HResult) requires an hresult, usually obtained through an exception, whereas WSAGetLastError() returns the last error on the socket directly.  And, the error codes do not match between the two methods.

Comment: @Robert, I am trying to port sockets code to work on WinRT, too, and it is a real pain.  Microsoft seems to have designed the new interface with no thought toward backward compatibility.  If they stick to their design rule of any call taking more than 50 ms being async, then this probably will not change.

Comment: Thanks much for the follow up, I'll mark as answer. Yeah, I figured the async only aspect might cause me some pain. I didn't think they'd make such a major change without at least a hint of guidance or compatibility. I thought maybe my google skills were off. ;-)

I'm sure I'll be posting other questions on this topic, if for no other reason than to have something on record for anyone else looking to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Winsock isn't supported in WinRT.

As of October '14, it is. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/13/winsock-and-more-open-source-for-your-windows-store-apps/

Have rebuilt apps at my end with Winsock and can confirm it works.